# Combine columns having diffrent value in joining of table codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, mysqli

I have a 4 tables while executes this query it return

SELECT * FROM `couns_form`  JOIN `education_detail` ON `couns_form`.`form_id`=`education_detail`.`form_id` JOIN `work_experience` ON `couns_form`.`form_id`=`work_experience`.`form_id` JOIN `course_description` ON `couns_form`.`form_id`=`course_description`.`form_id` WHERE `couns_form`.`form_id` = '16'

```
    Array
{
    [0] => Array
    {
        [form_id] => 16
        [counId] => 2
        [teleId] => 4
        [name] => somthing
        [dob] => 06/07/2016
        [phone] => somthing
        [mobile] => somthing
        [email] => somthing@somthing.com
        [passport] => 5955686
        [expiry] => 07/07/2016
        [address] => 255505052
        [country] => USA
        [reference] => 
        [friend_name] => 
        [remarks] => 
        [mstatus] => single
        [date_of_marriage] => 
        [age_of_kids] => 
        [kids] => yes
        [visa_ref] => yes
        [visa_country] => canada
        [created] => 2016-07-26 23:54:03
        [updated] => 2016-07-26 23:54:03
        [id] => 24
        [education] => Camb
        [university] => Camb
        [start_year] => 2016-07-2
        [end_year] => 2016-07-2
        [percentage] => 2
        [employer_name] => q
        [designation] => w
        [from] => 15/07/2016
        [to] => 27/07/2016
        [course] => IELTS
        [testdate] => 05/07/2016
        [listening] => 2
        [reading] => 2
        [writing] => 2
        [speaking] => 2
        [total_score] => 33
    }

    [1] => Array
    {
        [form_id] => 16
        [counId] => 2
        [teleId] => 4
        [name] => somthing
        [dob] => 06/07/2016
        [phone] => somthing
        [mobile] => somthing
        [email] => somthing@somthing.com
        [passport] => 5955686
        [expiry] => 07/07/2016
        [address] => 255505052
        [country] => USA
        [reference] => 
        [friend_name] => 
        [remarks] => 
        [mstatus] => single
        [date_of_marriage] => 
        [age_of_kids] => 
        [kids] => yes
        [visa_ref] => yes
        [visa_country] => canada
        [created] => 2016-07-26 23:54:03
        [updated] => 2016-07-26 23:54:03
        [id] => 24
        [education] => DPS
        [university] => DPS2
        [start_year] => 27/07/2016
        [end_year] => 30/07/2016
        [percentage] => 4
        [employer_name] => q
        [designation] => w
        [from] => 15/07/2016
        [to] => 27/07/2016
        [course] => IELTS
        [testdate] => 05/07/2016
        [listening] => 2
        [reading] => 2
        [writing] => 2
        [speaking] => 2
        [total_score] => 33
    }
}
```

I want result in one array somthing like

```
t[0] => Array
    {
        [form_id] => 16
        [counId] => 2
        [teleId] => 4
        [name] => somthing
        [dob] => 06/07/2016
        [phone] => 9786356
        [mobile] => 988830505
        [email] => somthing@somthing.com
        [passport] => 5955686
        [expiry] => 07/07/2016
        [address] => 255505052
        [country] => USA
        [reference] => 
        [friend_name] => 
        [remarks] => 
        [mstatus] => single
        [date_of_marriage] => 
        [age_of_kids] => 
        [kids] => yes
        [visa_ref] => yes
        [visa_country] => canada
        [created] => 2016-07-26 23:54:03
        [updated] => 2016-07-26 23:54:03
        [id] => 24
        [education] => oxford,Camb
        [university] => oxford,Camb
        [start_year] => 6,2016-07-2
        [end_year] => 6,2016-07-2
        [percentage] => 2
        [employer_name] => q
        [designation] => w
        [from] => 15/07/2016
        [to] => 27/07/2016
        [course] => IELTS
        [testdate] => 05/07/2016
        [listening] => 2
        [reading] => 2
        [writing] => 2
        [speaking] => 2
        [total_score] => 33
    }
```

NOw:  is it possible with query or I have to done this with PHP functions.. help thanks

Comment: use LIMIT statement

Comment: Thanks.. but limit in not solution for this .I want my final array has all children but not repete theire parents .. valure   [education] => oxford,Camb
        [university] => oxford,Camb
        [start_year] => 6,2016-07-2
        [end_year] => 6,2016-07-2

Comment: The question is from we should get oxford value?

Comment: I gotta  desired result via query but its so huge is there a way to optimize??

Comment: here is a query i build... help me if we can make shorter or .anything else. http://awesomescreenshot.com/00961wrr90

Answer (score 0):

**Your query should be like this**

```
SELECT * FROM couns_form JOIN education_detail ON couns_form.form_id=education_detail.form_id JOIN work_experience ON couns_form.form_id=work_experience.form_id JOIN course_description ON couns_form.form_id=course_description.form_id WHERE couns_form.form_id = '16' GROUP BY couns_form.form_id
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks for reply but.. this will miss my second record from education table which should be combine in final result something like this. ** [education] => oxford,Camb
        [university] => oxford,Camb
        [start_year] => 6,2016-07-2
        [end_year] => 6,2016-07-2**

Comment: here is a query i build. it gives a desired result  but i want to make it little simpler or shorter http://awesomescreenshot.com/00961wrr90